# Should a TCP server acknowledge new data in a SACK packet?

Tags: tcp

I have a TCP server that will not acknowledge new data in a TCP packet from a client if SACK boundaries are set in the packet. In other words, when the client is in congestion recovery, the server will not accept new incoming data. Is this typical or at least RFC "compliant" to some degree?

Scenario:

Client and server are smoothly sending data back and forth. The server sends 500 bytes (let's call it packet A) and does not immediately receive an ACK. The client sends 2000 more bytes, and the server ACKs all 2000 bytes. The server sends 500 more bytes (let's call it packet B). The server receives 500 bytes of new data from the client with SACK left/right edges acknowledging packet B. It is clear that client did not receive packet A. The server retransmits packet A, but it does not increase its ACK number to acknowledge the 500 bytes of new data it received from the client. The server receives another 1000 bytes of new data from the client with ACK left right/edges only acknowledging packet B again. The server sends new data to the client, but, again, it does not increase its ACK number. The server retransmits packet A again, but it still does not increase its ACK number. This state continues until eventually the client acknowledges all data, then the server finally starts acknowledging new data from the client.

I did not find a conclusive answer from reviewing various RFCs so far.

Comment: Each direction is completely independent.  If the server receives data from the client and there is no packet loss in that direction, the server should acknowledge that data regardless of whether the client has sent a duplicate acknowledgement.  I wonder if there is a better forum in the stack exchange family for this question like https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com